# Fast switching (microsecond to nanosecond) voltage using 10V signal pulse

Tags: mosfet, switches, solid-state-relay, solid-state-devices

I have an application where i need to be able to switch from a 20V supply to a 40-50V (variable) supply in a very small amount of time. Ideally this changeover needs to be prompted with a signal pulse in the region 5-12V. It also needs to occur as fast as possible - the microsecond to nanosecond regime.

I have the power supplies ready and varying the voltage is also taken care of, however I've yet to find a suitable way to switch between the two at these speed.

Edit: Some more information about the application below.

I'm driving a CCD; an imaging device that converts light into electrical signal that is stored within pixels. The signal is read out and used to recontruct the original image. Within the pixels are seperate gates that have biases applied to transfer charge between one pixel to the next. This transfer process occurs in the us to ns regime depending on operation speed.

The typical gate voltage is around 20V for this device. I need to be able to increase this gate voltage from 20V to 40V and then reduce it to 20V again in a time comparable to the speed at which charge is transferred from one pixel to the next. The gate voltage is currently controlled by a power supply that contols the low level, the plan was to add another that controls the high level and to switch between the two quite fast. I'm trying to design a ciruit that interfaces the power supplys and supplies the voltage needed to the gate of the CCD.

Ideally I'd like a switch where when its in the "off" state, the 20V is being supplied and when its in the "on" state the high voltage is supplied. There needs to be no time where no voltage whatsoever is supplied (I may have about 1-5ns of grace, but not much room for error).

I'd previously done this by hooking up a couple of relays, but they are too slow. Is there a faster alternative out there that i can get hold of in a single IC package?

In terms of requirements the max voltage will be about 50V DC. the max current draw will be about 200mA.

Forgive me if the answer is very simple, however I've searched for answers with not much luck.

Comment: Bear in mind that even with really quick switching, any capacitance on the line is going to cause it to take a lot longer to actually reach the new voltage. Is this a problem for your application?

Comment: Microsecond or nanosecond - about 1000:1 (or greater tolerance) on what you want. Why not explain from a higher level what you really want to achieve. Try and justify why a hold-up capacitor isn't the easiest and obvious solution?

Comment: Nick - there is capacitence on the line, about 65pF or so. The time to rise to this voltage should not be an issue as long as its below about a 1us.  Andy - I'll add some more information to the opening post. Basically its a case of faster is better, lower than a 1us to reach the new voltage will be seen as a success.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Read what respawned fluff says - I'm getting the impression you are designing a solution without specifying the problem. Describe how quickly the 20 V signal must change into the 40 V signal then state the minimum time that the 40V signal must be present then describe the time taken to get back to 20V or some other voltage. Don't think switching devices - think fully variable power supply that is fast-enough at operating to meet your needs.

Comment: Your CCD seems to need more voltage than [that of a space telescope](http://trace.tennessee.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1033&context=utk_gradthes). There are commercial CCD driver ICs out there, but not for this voltage.

Comment: Is it [one of these fully depleted CCDs](http://ipo.lbl.gov/lbnl2028/)?

Comment: The majority of the CCD is driven by a dedicated IC, its just one phase i need to change supply to. Its an EMCCD in particular, and the phase in question is the R2HV phase. I also only need to do it once per frame (ie i dont need to keep clocking it, just one pull up and push down before readout)

Answer (score 6):

Connect the 20 V supply with a series Schottky diode, then a transistor between the 50 V supply and the load.

When the transistor is off, the load is powered from the 20 V supply.  When the transistor is on, the load is powered from the 50 V supply.  At that point, the diode between the two supplies is reverse biased, so the 20 V supply is essentially cut off.  There is guaranteed to be no off time.  The switchover time is how fast the transistor can be turned on, and what dV/dt it can produce or tolerate on its output.

For the transistor, a P channel MOSFET is probably the best choice.  A circuit takes the 10 V signal and converts that to a FET gate drive signal.

Comment: Personaly, I would add a resitor and small cap. The pulse would have an energy ammount of the cap charge, while the resitor would prevent fast charging of the cap, so only short pulse wil lbe generated

Comment: I think Olin means something like this. The values are not optimized, but it's a start. http://i.stack.imgur.com/yquHX.png

Comment: Low capacitance schottky diode